# Using session var as like test parameter

Tags: php, session, pdo

I want to use session to get rid of GET parameter
here is the test

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $_SESSION['etat']="pasdecompte";
}
```

and then

```
if(@$_SESSION['etat']=="pasdecompte"){
    echo "<div id='msg'>Vérifier votre login et/ou mot de passe</div>";
    $_SESSION['etat']="";
}
```

Its working without  `$_SESSION['etat']="";` but i need to clear the test and prevent it form showing again for exemple when i reload the page ,
i just want to see the error(the div) only after the submit

Ps: i cant give all the code and i wont use the GET params

Comment: What problem are you facing ? Do you have any errors ?

Comment: you can use session_destroy(); or unset() after being echo message.

Comment: the div its always showing up i want it to be shown only after the post not everytime when i refrech the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_SESSION['etat']) && $_SESSION['etat']=="pasdecompte"){

  echo "<div id='msg'>Vérifier votre login et/ou mot de passe</div>";
   unset($_SESSION['etat']);

}
```

Comment: i didnt understand. explain

Answer (score 1):

you can unset session

```
if(@$_SESSION['etat']=="pasdecompte"){
echo "<div id='msg'>Vérifier votre login et/ou mot de passe</div>";
unset($_SESSION['etat']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [unset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) function or [session-destroy](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php) to clear session value.

Comment: i used both but its the same